# Capture Copy&Paste Key

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm working on an OpenGL game in Cocoa, and need to capture when the user attempts to copy or paste (via command+c, or command+v).

So far, I have an `NSView<NSTextInputClient>` as the first-respondant of my `NSWindow`. It is successful in allowing non-ASCII characters to be typed into my game (中文維基百科, for example) but I'm lost trying to capture Copy&Paste.

I think I might be able to get a working solution using `flagsChanged` combined with `keyDown`, but this feels like a hack, and I'm sure someone out there knows a better solution. :)

**Edit**: For clarity, I'm looking mainly for the existence of a predefined Copy event or keycode. The rationale being that if I manually define Copy as "Command+C" then that might break if a user has remapped his/her keys or is using some accessibility tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `NSEvent` class method: `+ (id)addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:(NSEventMask)mask handler:(void (^)(NSEvent*))block`

or you can implement `- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent`

```
- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {

    if ([theEvent modifierFlags] & NSCommandKeyMask) {
        NSString *character = [theEvent charactersIgnoringModifiers];
        if ([character isEqualToString:@"c"]) {
            NSLog(@"Capture Copy&Paste Key");
        }
    }
    [super keyDown:theEvent];
}
```

Comment: Interesting find, but wouldn't it be more suited if I used `addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask`? Also, I can't find a suited `NSEventType` / `NSEventMaskFromType` for catching copy or paste.

Comment: You can use keyCode.NSInteger keyCode =[theEvent keyCode];

Comment: There's no keyCode that I can find for a Copy or Paste event. `interpretKeyEvents` looked like the right idea, but it's sending me a `noop:` selector when I Command+C or Command+V.

Comment: if (8==keyCode) {
   NSLog(@"Command +c");
  }  else if (9==keyCode) {
   NSLog(@"command+v")
  }

Comment: That I have to decide in my application what key modifiers and codes constitute a "Copy" operation is kinda lame, but it's looking like that is the best solution. You should update your post to use keycode though, as others may not know that not all keyboard layouts have a "c" key, and thus won't be able to copy&paste.

Comment: How to get pasted text here ??